Derivation of steepest descent direction in a Riemannian space as in Amari 1998 - Natural gradient works efficiently in learning
I am trying to follow the steps to proof the theorem 1 in the work of Shun-ichi Amari (1998): Natural gradient works efficiently in learning
This is the relevant section of the proof:




However when I try to follow the Lagrange method step I miss an $\varepsilon$. I assume we are constructing the Lagrange function for the following constrained optimizaton problem:
$$
d\boldsymbol{w}^* = \text{argmin}_{d\boldsymbol{w}} L(\boldsymbol{w} + d\boldsymbol{w}) \quad \text{s.t.} \|a\|^2 = 1
$$
Where $d\boldsymbol{w} := \varepsilon d\boldsymbol{a}$.
So I cunstruct the Lagrange function $\mathcal{L}$ by substracting the constrain $\| \boldsymbol{a} \|^2 -1 = 0$ from the cost function $L$:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{a}, \lambda) &= L(\boldsymbol{w} + d\boldsymbol{w}) - \lambda(\| \boldsymbol{a} \|^2 -1 ) \\
&= L(\boldsymbol{w}) + \varepsilon \nabla L(\boldsymbol{w})^T\boldsymbol{a} - \lambda(\boldsymbol{a}^T G \boldsymbol{a} -1 ) \\
\end{align}
$$
Now Amari considers the partial derivative wrt. to $a_i$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{∂a_i}\mathcal{L}(\boldsymbol{w}, \boldsymbol{a}, \lambda) &= \frac{\partial}{∂a_i}\left(\varepsilon \nabla L(\boldsymbol{w})^T\boldsymbol{a} - \lambda\boldsymbol{a}^T G \boldsymbol{a} \right) = 0 \\
\Leftrightarrow \nabla L(\boldsymbol{w}) &= \frac{2 \lambda}{\varepsilon} G\boldsymbol{a}
\end{align}
$$
Why is the $\varepsilon$ not appearing in Amaris derivation? Is it because he actually used a substituted $\tilde\lambda = \frac{\lambda}{\varepsilon}$ because it doesn't really matter for Lagrange multiplier?

We want to minimize $$L(w)+\epsilon \nabla L(w)^Ta$$
This is equivalent to minimizing $$\epsilon \nabla L(w)^Ta$$ since $L(w)$ is a constant.
Furthermore, it is equivalent to minimizing $$ \nabla L(w)^Ta$$
since $\epsilon$ is a positive constant and hence that is why we can drop it.
In the end of the day, what is of interest is the direction, $G^{-1}\nabla L(w)$. Your Langrange multiplier and his Langrange multiplier differ by a difference of $\epsilon$ being multiplied.
